# PHP conditional string replacement str_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

This is the string i'm trying to replace white spaces *between the words* with "-".

```
$mystring = "Color red, Color blue, Color black";
$newstring = str_replace(' ', '-', $mystring);
```

What i want to achieve, using the str_replace function, is:

```
"Color-red, Color-blue, Color-black";
```

But that returns:

```
"Color-red,-Color-blue,-Color-black";
```

I guess i need a condition that replaces white spaces "not after the comma" or "between two words".
But i have no idea. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?<!,)\s`

That uses a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match all spaces (`\s`) that aren't followed by a `,`.

```
preg_replace("/(?<!,)\s/", '-', $mystring);
```

[Play with the regex here](http://regexr.com?316rg).